# Code executes outside of Loop while same code gives 'Uninitialized string offset' notice inside a while loop

Tags: functions, loop, array

It's strange that when I run the code below in a function, it executes it, but when I run it inside a while loop it gives me this notice:

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 4

```
function thing($content) {

preg_match_all("/(<h[^>]*>.*?<\/h2>\n*<p>.*?<\/p>)/", $content, $array);

$i = 1;
$limit = count($array[0]);

$array = $array[0][4];
echo $array; //outside loop

while ( $i <= $limit) {
  $array = $array[0][4];
  echo $array; inside loop
  $i++;
}
return $content;
}
add_action('the_content', 'thing', 50);
```

Why is this happening?

I want to access the array keys one at a time so doing this `$array = $array[0][4];` is required

Answer (score 0):

That error means you're attempting to address a string or null as if it were an array. Perhaps it's returning fewer than 5 matches, in which case `$array[0][4]` would be unset.

Here's your problem:

```
function thing($content) {

preg_match_all("/(<h[^>]*>.*?<\/h2>\n*<p>.*?<\/p>)/", $content, $array);

$i = 1;
$limit = count($array[0]);

$array = $array[0][4]; // you've overwritten $array with what used to be $array[0][4]
echo $array; //outside loop

while ( $i <= $limit) {
  $array = $array[0][4]; // now you're trying to overwrite $array again once for every time you go around the loop
  echo $array; inside loop
  $i++;
}
return $content;
}
add_action('the_content', 'thing', 50);
```

Let's rewrite it a bit:

```
function thing($content) {

preg_match_all("/(<h[^>]*>.*?<\/h2>\n*<p>.*?<\/p>)/", $content, $array);

$i = 1;
$limit = count($array[0]);

echo $array[0][4]; //outside loop

while ( $i <= $limit) {
  echo $array[0][4]; // inside loop
  $i++;
}
return $content;
}
add_action('the_content', 'thing', 50);
```

This still isn't great code as it assumes the array is 5 members and repeats the same value each time it loops. Let's rewrite the while loop into a for:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++ ) {
  echo $array[0][$i]; // inside loop
}
```

Comment: You can use `is_array` to be sure `$array` is actually an array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Comment: When I use `var_dump($array);` it shows that it's a multidimensional array which contains two arrays and each of those two arrays contain 5 keys

Comment: Ok, but why are you trying to get the 4th value specifically?

Comment: Also, the third parameter of `preg_match_all()` is an array http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: On line 8 you set the value of $array to $array[0][4]. You do the same again at line 12 within the while loop, which would refer to $array[0][4][0][4] which doesn't exist in the original array.

Comment: That doesn't sound right.

Comment: the `is_array()` function returns false. If it's not an array then why does `var_dump()` show that it is an array? very confusing

Comment: I've edited my answer with code examples.